# EF.Core 8.x with Pomelo Adapter for mariadb -> JSON array length?

Tags: json, entity-framework-core, mariadb, ef-core-8.0

On EF.core 8.x with mariaDB I have problems querying into JSON columns using LINQ syntax.

The table `Analyses` contains a JSON column called `Data`

This simple query

```
 var list = dbContext.Analyses.Include(a => a.Site)
     .Where(a => a.Data.Count > 0)
     .ToList();
```

fails with

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Analysis>()
          .Count(a => a.Data.Count > 0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

I've added `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Json.Microsoft 8.0.2` and added builder options:

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseMySql(options.ConnectionString, GetServerVersion(), builderOptions => builderOptions.UseMicrosoftJson());
```

Now the query above does no longer fail but the resulting query returns 0 rows:

```sql
SELECT `a`.`Id`, `a`.`Data`, `a`.`LastAnalysisDateTime`, `a`.`Result`, `a`.`SiteId`, `s`.`Id`, `s`.`Domain`, `s`.`LastResolvedDateTime`, `s`.`ResolvedDomain`
FROM `Analyses` AS `a`
INNER JOIN `Sites` AS `s` ON `a`.`SiteId` = `s`.`Id`
WHERE CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(`a`.`Data`, '$.Count') AS signed) > 0
```

Trying this query in a db management tool yields the same result. The JSON_EXTRACT thing with the JSON selector `$.Count` seem to be the wrong approach.

There is so little documentation about the EF.core with JSON support for *mariadb* that I actually have no ideas on how to fix this.

According to maria db docs the where clause (which looks overly complicated to me) can be easily written as

```sql
WHERE JSON_LENGTH(`a`.`Data`)  > 0
```

(which works correctly).

But I see no good way of implementing this beside using raw db queries, skipping entirely the hydration (the creation of tracked EF object) and effectively by-passing EF.

Did somebody else had any success with EF.core, JSON and mariadb?

Comment: `which works correctly` but has to parse *every* row to calculate the length. What does `Analyses.Data` contain when there's no data? NULL? Empty string? `[]` ? It's faster to use `When a.Data IS NOT NULL AND a.Data NOT IN ('','[]')` than calculate the length of all values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree, your query would be more efficient. Thanks for the improvement.

Comment: Querying inside JSON, XML, YAML is always inefficient *unless* the database offers a way to index and query the data. PostgreSQL does, MariaDB doesn't